# PostgreSQL select data in time interval using SQL subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a probably trivial SQL question. My PostgreSQL database has two tables, namely "logging" and "debug_data". The former is used for logging events provided from my systems. These event can be errors, warnings or just some system info. The "debug_data" contains more detailed information which is updated more frequently and can be used to determine the root cause of errors or warning. Each table contains a column with a time stamp provided by the PostgreSQL database for timing consistency.
What I want to do is select the timestamp of the latest 5 error events from "logging". Then get the debug data in an interval of +/- 2 minutes around this timestamp from "debug_data".

How would a proper SQL query look like? So far I got this:

```
select * from debug_data in
(select timestamp from logging where level='error' order by timestamp asc limit 5)
```

This will provide me with any debug_data entries which match the logging timestamp. I am not sure how to implement the timestamp interval selection on debug_data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we get the 5 latest entries in the log table. Then we take the MIN() and MAX() timestamp values and expand that window by 2 minutes. After that we join the CTE on the debug table. I work in MS SQL but I think this also works in PostGre.

```
 WITH GetTop5 AS (
      SELECT timestamp
      FROM logging
      WHERE where level='error' order by timestamp desc limit 5

 ),
 GetMinMax AS (
       SELECT MAX(timestamp) + interval '2 min' as 'max_timestamp',
              MIN(timestamp) - interval '2 min' as 'min_timestamp'
       FROM GetTop5

 )
 SELECT * FROM debug_data d
     JOIN GetMinMax ON
         d.timestamp >= GetMinMax.min_timestamp
         AND d.timestamp <= GetMinMax.max_timestamp
```

Simplified version:

```
WITH GetTop5 AS (
      SELECT timestamp
      FROM logging
      WHERE where level='error' order by timestamp desc limit 5

 )
 SELECT * FROM debug_data d
     JOIN GetTop5 ON
         d.timestamp >= MIN(timestamp) - interval '2 min'
         AND d.timestamp <= MAX(timestamp) + interval '2 min'
```

Comment: Ordering in a derived table or table expression is required is you are using a `limit / top` expression to restrict rows and you require deterministic results!

Comment: But this is `MAX(timestamp)` and `MIN(timestamp`, so ORDERING, and using LIMIT, is not needed, you will only get 1 row with result, and ordering such a row is hard... 

Comment: @Luuk Good catch! It's always too easy when you write it in your head. I've added an extra CTE. This should work :D

Comment: The above approach is correct, but as posted it will not work in Postgres. The function `dateadd` **does not exist**. Postgres does not require a function to accomplish this, you can just add an `interval` to the timestamp. Replace `DATEADD(minute,2,MAX(timestamp))` with  `max(timestamp) + interval '2 min'`.  And similarly `min(timestamp) - interval '2 min'`.

Comment: @Belayer Alright, I will add this change. Thank you.

Comment: That solved my problem for the most part. I had to play around with limiting the results. Also PostgreSQL does not seem to implement DATEADD.
Instead I used this:

with mydate as (
 select date_trunc
 from logging
 order by date_trunc asc
 limit 5
)
select * from debug_data d
join mydate on
d.sqltime>mydate.date_trunc - interval '1' minute and
d.sqltime<mydate.date_trunc + interval '1' minute 
limit 100